# railsinstaller for windows 7 with ruby > 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7

is it possible to install rails on windows 7 (64bit) with ruby version higher than 1.9.3?
[Rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) seems to be a little bit out-dated, it comes with ruby 1.9.3-p125.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.2.2 was recently released with a higher patch level of 1.9.3. Additionally, you can grab the prerelease of RailsInstaller 3.0.0 with Ruby 2.0.0 from [Github](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/releases/tag/3.0.0-alpha.2).

Evan